# Limit exercise from Rudin: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2+n} -n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals

This is Chapter 3, Exercise 2 of Rudin's Principles.

Calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2+n} -n$.

Hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}{1} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2}}{1}\times \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2}} = \cdots$$
I will expand more if needed.

Comment: So $1/2$ is the final answer, huh? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, 1/2 is correct.

Answer (score 5):

$\sqrt{n^2+n} - n= \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n} + n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1n} + 1}$

Comment: Or $\sqrt{n^2+n}=n \left(1+\frac 1n \right)^{\frac 12}=n \left(1 + \frac{1}{2n} -\frac{1}{8n^2} + o \left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right)\right)$

Answer (score 4):

When you have a sequence that involves difference between two roots, it's often a good idea to try using the identity $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2$ to git rid of the root difference:
$$
\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} = \left(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\right)\frac{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}} = \frac{\left(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\right)\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\right)}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}} = \frac{a - b}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}}
$$

Comment: @ Ayman Hourieh : Thanks. In general the identity $$(a-b) \: \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} a^{p-1-k}b^k =a^p-b^p$$ where $p$ is a positive integer is used when we have limits with $\sqrt[p]{\text{expression 1}} - \sqrt[p]{\text{expression 2}}$ .

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea of what the answer *might* be, I tried inputting values: n=100, n=1000, n=1000000.
e.g. for n = 1000,
sqrt(1000000 + 1000) ~ 1000 + 1/2 because (1000 + 1/2)^2 = 1000000 + 2*1000*(1/2) + 1/4 ~ 1000000 + 1000.

If you can spot this, then the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by inductively showing it is increasing and bounded, but their ideas are probably a better route.

Comment: This will show that the limit exists; OP asked to compute it.

Comment: You can also show the least upper bound is 1/2 however...